# Some Games Give you extremely high rates of growth that taper down as you play. How do you calculate the inverse of exponential growth?

Tags: logic

Exponential growth means as time goes on, your number gets larger and larger faster.

Some games do the opposite with their economy to make the early progress a player makes easier *then* harder over time.

How do you calculate the inverse of exponential growth if you know:

1. Time until reach end growth
2. Number player's growth ends at

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [logarithmic growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_growth). The inverse function of $t^2$ is $log_2(t)$. There isn't one particular formula based on the two variables you have given, since just like with exponential growth, many different functions can pass through the same point, and your criteria only determine a single point $(t, y)$.